# Import Error: No module named settings in Django

Tags: django, geodjango

I am going on with http://kw20kb.wikidot.com/geodjango. I created a urls.py inside my project folder and added the below line in it.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('waypoints.urls')),
)
```

When i run my development server i am getting the error

```
Import Error: No module named settings
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead use:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

More information on using [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) can be found in the documentation.